# How do I process attachements programatically, from the model, without using forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, carrierwave, rmagick

I have a `LineItem` class that has an `images` column. It belongs to an `Order` class. When a `line_item` is saved, the `images` column is a list of comma delimited image urls.

I want is to create a collage from the urls and save it as an attachment of the `line_item` instance.

I'm not sure where to start, though. Any idea what my work flow should look like?

Should I even use CarrierWave? Where should the image processing happen? In the `LineItem` model or the uploader file provided by CarrierWave?

Comment: line_item should have_many images (rather than store as a CSV column)

Comment: I agree with you, and that was my first thought. But I'm not allowed to change the view level :/